# 権限が増えるため、通知は何語になりますか？

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

過去に、Reputationによる権限が増える時、通知が下記のように英語でした：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

開発者が直したらしいですが、誰かが権限を増えたら、ちゃんと日本語になっているかを確認ください。